# Phase transitions graph

Tags: plotting, code-request

I have temperature `T` in terms of `r` as

```
T = 1/(4 Pi r) + 2 P r^2
```

and `G` in terms of `r` as

```
G = r/4 - 2(Pi P r^3)/3
```

How can I plot `G` vs. `T` in Mathematica? Assume `P = 1/(96π)` or `P = 0.01`.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and at which specific step did you get stuck? (Please edit the question and add this information.)

Comment: For `P=1`. Try: `ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@(Eliminate[{T == 1/(4*Pi*r) + 2*P*r^2, 
      G == r/4 - 2 (Pi*P*r^3)/3}, r] /. P -> 1), {T, -1, 2}, {G, -1, 
  2}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]`

Comment: Can you please make it for given values. i need the same as above given in figure.

Comment: Szabolcs, kindly check  now.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `ParametricPlot` and I recommend defining `G` and `T` as functions. Like so:

```
T[P_, r_] := 1/(4 π r) + 2 P r^2
G[P_, r_] := r/4 - 2 (π P r^3)/3
With[{p = 1./(96 π)},
  ParametricPlot[{T[p, r], G[p, r]}, {r, 0.00001, 2. π},
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"T", "G"}),
    AspectRatio -> 1]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: How you give the value of {r, 0.00001, 2. π}?

Comment: @Ahmed1. There is a singularity at `r = 0`, so I offset the lower bound at little. The upper was chosen arbitrarily.